# Difference between predict() and model$coefficiest*vector in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, linear-regression, predict

I have been facing a strange problem in R.
I have a dataframe (let's call it df) and perform a lm regression over 70% of it. Then, if I use the predict function or if I multiply the coefficients by the values I get extremely different results. The code is more or less like that:

```
df.train<-df[1:floor(0.7*(dim(df)[2])),]
df.test<-df[ceiling(0.7*(dim(df)[2])):(dim(df)[2]),]
model<-lm(df.train$y ~ ., data = df.train)
prev.1<-predict(model, df.test)
prev.2<-model$coefficiets*df.test
```

and prev.1 and prev.2 have completely different results, same dimensions but the values are very different. Anyone know what I am doing wrong or the reason why it happens?

Thank you very much!

PS.: The reason why I would like to use coefficients instead of model is because the dataframe is very large, so the regression takes too long, and I would like to use the regression model many time and not only in R, hence I would like to use the regression coefficients to make my estimations.

edit1:

```
structure(list(y = c(0.0150000000000006, 0.200000000000003, 
0.0500000000000114, 0.0450000000000017, 0.0919999999999987, -0.203000000000003, 
0.0809999999999889, 0.0300000000000011, -104.742, 0.109999999999999
), x1 = c(-2e+05, -2e+05, -2e+05, -1e+05, -1e+05, -2e+05, 
-2e+05, -2e+05, -6e+05, -2e+05), x2 = c(5792000, 2625000, 
2800000, 3503000, 3620000, 2600000, 5324000, 5154000, 6e+05, 
4600000), x3 = c(102.395, 106.45, 106.6, 109.425, 
101.858, 101.113, 100.989, 100.69, 104.742, 100.72), x4 = c(-0.226136, 
0.189501, 0.09438, 0.124337, 0.416603, 0.414208, 0.285315, -0.143832, 
0.077198, 0.354898), x5 = c(226.553070111768, -887.582025126621, 
-172.120001039611, -390.77670409382, -1482.58537715873, -1707.54899438474, 
-794.919752641787, 359.680881832913, -131.174668288603, -1343.65207551945
), x6 = c(0.00013775, 0.000659, 0.000658, 0.0006465, 0.0006495, 
0.000659, 8.301e-05, 0.000658, 0.0006465, 0.0006495), x7 = c(16.55, 
30.51, 47.32, 39.59, 66.31, 42.44, 57.54, 22.35, 36.15, 57.96
), x8 = c(1.61815068493, 1.01404109589, 1.920541, 
1.08948087432, 0.63047945205, 0.26366868778, 0.03756830601, 0.03756830601, 
0.97950819672, 0.27053182124), x9= c(1.14, 6.68, 1.54, 
3.48, 4.04, 6.4, 2.88, 1.79, 3.28, 4.46), x10 = c(1e+09, 
4e+08, 5e+08, 5e+08, 6e+08, 2.5e+08, 8e+08, 9e+08, 344731000, 
7.5e+08), x11 = c(1.875, 1.125, 4.339, 2.75, 0.875, 0.5, 0.625, 
0.25, 1.5, 0.523), x12 = c(6.85753424657534, 4.8958904109589, 
8.44109589041096, 6.39178082191781, 0.715068493150685, 0.520547945205479, 
0.556164383561644, 1.14246575342466, 5.14520547945205, 0.50958904109589
), x13 = c(0.145205479452055, 6.11232876712329, 0.567123287671233, 
2.61369863013699, 3.0986301369863, 5.49041095890411, 1.95068493150685, 
0.86027397260274, 2.35616438356164, 3.81369863013699), x14 = c(1000, 
1000, 1e+05, 1000, 1000, 1e+05, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000), x15 = c(1000, 
1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05
), x16 = c(9.73460631843944, 1.84208986474756, 10.9953858843485, 
5.92998643613249, 3.6746119178749, 3.13262576244204, 0.961210168020342, 
0.455490971922174, 5.04443516437687, 1.86646134416743), x17 = c(2e+05, 
2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05
), x18 = c(603.036342, 603.036342, 603.036342, 603.036342, 
603.036342, 603.036342, 603.036342, 603.036342, 603.036342, 603.036342
), x19 = c(113.456851, 113.456851, 113.456851, 113.456851, 
113.456851, 113.456851, 113.456851, 113.456851, 113.456851, 113.456851
)), row.names = c(8L, 9L, 26L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
56L), class = "data.frame")
```

edit2:

```
structure(list(y = c(0.0150000000000006, 0.200000000000003, 
0.0500000000000114, 0.0450000000000017, 0.0919999999999987, -0.203000000000003, 
0.0809999999999889, 0.0300000000000011, -104.742, 0.109999999999999
), x1 = c(-2e+05, -2e+05, -2e+05, -1e+05, -1e+05, -2e+05, 
-2e+05, -2e+05, -6e+05, -2e+05), x2 = c(5792000, 2625000, 
2800000, 3503000, 3620000, 2600000, 5324000, 5154000, 6e+05, 
4600000), x3 = c(102.395, 106.45, 106.6, 109.425, 
101.858, 101.113, 100.989, 100.69, 104.742, 100.72), x4 = c(-0.226136, 
0.189501, 0.09438, 0.124337, 0.416603, 0.414208, 0.285315, -0.143832, 
0.077198, 0.354898), x19 = c(113.456851, 113.456851, 113.456851, 113.456851, 
113.456851, 113.456851, 113.456851, 113.456851, 113.456851, 113.456851
)), row.names = c(8L, 9L, 26L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 
56L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `prev.2` is just the product of values in vectors whereas `prev.1` is using the matriz model behind `lm` to make predictions.

Comment: Please provide minimal and reproducible example(s) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data...

Comment: @sindri_baldur What kind of examples do you want?

Comment: We cannot run your code without a data.frame called `df`. So just share a small data.frame this is enough for running the code.

Comment: @sindri_baldur I did dput() for the first 10 lines of my dataframe, is it helpfull?

Comment: @LucasMatosMolter something is missing from the beginning of the output. Also do you *need* all the columns. Maybe 3-4 columns would be enough to illustrate the issue?

Comment: @sindri_baldur sure, you can use edit2